# Given paramaters of an Edward's curve and x, determine a y value if it exists

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption, finite-field, hybrid-encryption

I'm making a demonstration [cryptosystem](https://github.com/ThePlasmaRailgun/FinCrypt) using ECC ElGamal. I've currently got a working implementation of Edward's Curve operations and a basic ElGamal implementation (Encrypts only points on the curve), and in order to perform the mapping operation described in [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62966/how-to-securely-map-messages-to-points-on-an-elliptic-curve), I need to determine the $y$ value of a point on an Edward's curve $g$ given an $x$. I have a basic understanding of the way an Edward's curve works but the finite fields are a bit much for me to be confident in properly implementing this based on intuition. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for an Edwards curve is $x^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$. Assuming you know the curve parameters then, given that you know $x$, you are solving the above equation for one unknown, namely $y$. We can rewrite this as a quadratic equation in one unknown and solve it. Note that all operations are $\bmod{p}$ where $p$ is the characteristic of the field the curve is defined over (remember that dividing by $z$ is equivalent to multiplying by $z^{-1}\bmod{p}$, square roots also have different rules).

$$x^2 + y^2 = 1 + dx^2y^2$$
$$y^2 - dx^2y^2 + x^2 - 1 = 0$$
$$(1 - dx^2)y^2 + (x^2 - 1) = 0$$

Now let $a = (1 - dx^2)$, $b = 0$, and $c = (x^2 - 1)$ (so we have $ay^2 + by + c = 0$ i.e. a quadratic equation). Note that you can also move some terms around in the upper equation and end up at the same result.

$$y = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
$$y = \frac{-0 \pm \sqrt{0 - 4(1 - dx^2)(x^2 - 1)}}{2(1 - dx^2)}$$
$$y = \frac{\pm \sqrt{-4(1 - dx^2)(x^2 - 1)}}{2(1 - dx ^2)}$$
$$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{1 - x^2}{1 - dx^2}}$$

Now substitute in $x$ and $d$. Note that there are two solutions to the equation. Without your x coordinate having some sort of encoding that indicates which y value should be used it is impossible to recover the "correct" y as both values result in distinct valid points.

Comment: Thank you! When you say all operations are mod p, does that mean every operation I do in the final equation has to be mod p

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an appropriate solution for extremely large values of d or x, Python's sqrt operator returns an overflow error.

Comment: Well in this case the square root is a modular square root (since it's in a field), which is different than pythons sqrt function (which additionally operates on floats not integers, the max value that a float can represent is usually much less than the values numbers take in a cryptographic context). Use [Tonelli-Shanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) to find square roots in the context of modular arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks, just figured that out before you posted. However, it's currently very slow because I'm calulating for each x value what the y value is if it exists. Is there a similar check to just see if a y value exists in a way that is faster than calculating the y value?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you mean that you're trying to enumerate all possible x values in the field the curve is over and their corresponding y values? For a secure curve this will be computationally intractable (enumerating all x is more or less equivalent to solving ECDLP).

Comment: No, I just want some fast method of taking an x value and seeing if a y value exists, without having to actually compute the y value.

Comment: It'll boil down to finding out whether the term $\frac{1 - x^2}{1 - dx^2}$ has a modular square root. See [this math SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2444094) for more details.